# How to reduce the conditional overhead in this example by using "dynamic" code

Tags: python

In this naive code example I have the problem that each time .do() is invoked a list of conditions needs to be processed in order to have the class behave as expected.  This is not very efficient, and I'm pretty sure there is another way but I can't put my finger on it.

What approach I could do to make this class more behave the same but in a more  efficient way?

```
class translate():
    def __init__(self, EN=True, FR=False, DE=False, SP=False):
        self.EN=EN
        self.FR=FR
        self.DE=DE
        self.SP=SP

    def do(self, word):
        if self.EN:
            self.en(word)
        if self.FR:
            self.fr(word)
        if self.DE:
            self.de(word)
        if self.SP:
            self.sp(word)

    def en(self, word):
        print "In English: %s"%(word)

    def fr(self, word):
        print "In French: %s"%(word)

    def de(self, word):
        print "In German: %s"%(word)    

    def sp(self, word):
        print "In Spanish: %s"%(word)

tr=translate(FR=True)
tr.do("blah")
```

I could so something like this but then I can only do 1 language:

```
    class translate():
    def __init__(self, EN=False, FR=False, DE=False, SP=False):
        if EN:
            self.do=self.en
        elif FR:
            self.do=self.fr
        elif DE:
            self.do=self.de
        elif SP:
            self.do=self.sp
        else:
            self.do=self.unkown

    def en(self, word):
        print "In English: %s"%(word)

    def fr(self, word):
        print "In French: %s"%(word)

    def de(self, word):
        print "In German: %s"%(word)    

    def sp(self, word):
        print "In Spanish: %s"%(word)

    def unknown(self, word):
        print "Unknown: %s"%(word)

tr=translate(FR=True)
tr.do("blah")
```

Comment: mgilson is right, you could use (language, word) as key of this dictionary.

Comment: As far as i see, he wants to be able to translate in several languages once.

Comment: If you use `(lang, word)` as the dictionary key, it becomes pretty difficult to actually extract the data by word or by language, as to do either, you need to iterate over the full list of keys.  Structured data would work better in this case, since the usage pattern is to get all translations for a given word.

Comment: I'm sorry that my "translator example" is steering your in this direction that was not my intention. It's my intention to be able to initialize the class in such a way I don't require the conditionals in the .do() function.

Answer (score 4):

In your original code, `do` can call more than one translation method.
Therefore, we should keep track of a list (or perhaps a set) of translation methods:

```
class Translate():
    def __init__(self, EN=True, FR=False, DE=False, SP=False):
        self.translators = [method for lang, method in
                            zip((EN, FR, DE, SP),
                                (self.en, self.fr, self.de, self.sp))
                            if lang]

    def do(self, word):
        for method in self.translators:
            method(word)

    def en(self, word):
        print "In English: %s" % (word)

    def fr(self, word):
        print "In French: %s" % (word)

    def de(self, word):
        print "In German: %s" % (word)

    def sp(self, word):
        print "In Spanish: %s" % (word)

tr = Translate(FR=True)
tr.do("blah")
```

yields

```
In English: blah
In French: blah
```

Comment: `do` could be named `__call__`, to call the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually storing translations anywhere, so you are just going to print the word as spelled when you input it for each language for which the object was initialized for.  You need a system that lets you store and retrieve translations and that will give you all the values for which a translation is set for a given word.  This would work:

```
class WordTranslationMap(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self, languages)
        for language in languages:
            self[language] = None

    def all(self):
        for language, translation in self.iteritems():
            if translation is not None:
               yield (language, translation)

class TranslationDictionary(dict):

    def __init__(supported_languages=['EN', 'SP', 'FR', 'DE']):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.supported_languages = supported_languages

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            word = WordTranslationMap(self.supported_languages)
            self[key] = word
            return word

words = TranslationDictionary()
words['hello']['EN'] = 'hello'
words['hello']['FR'] = 'bonjour'
for translation in words['hello'].all:
     print translation
```

Alternatively, organize by language first:

```
class WordToken(object):
    def __init__(value, translation_dictionary, word_id=None):
        self.value = value
        self.word_id = translation_dictionary.next_id.next() if word_id is None else word_id
        self.translation_dictionary= translation_dictionary

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.translation_dictionary[key][self.word_id]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.translation_dictionary[key][self.word_id] = value

    def all(self):
        for language, translations in self.translation_dictionary.language_dictionaries.iteritems():
            try:
                yield (language, str(translations[self.word_id]))
            except KeyError:
                pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class LanguageDictionary(dict):

    def __init__(self, translation_dictionary):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.translation_dictionary = translation_dictionary

    def add_word(self, word):
        word = WordToken(word, self.translation_dictionary)
        self[word.word_id] = word

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            if value.word_id != key:
                raise ValueError('Tried to set translation to word object that does not match language dictionary key.')
        except AttributeError:
            value = WordToken(value, self.translation_dictionary, key)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

class TranslationDictionary(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.next_id = itertools.count(start=0, step=1)
        self.language_dictionaries = defaultdict(LanguageDictionary)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.language_dictionaries[key]

dictionary = TranslationDictionary()
dictionary['EN'].add_word('hello')
dictionary['EN']['hello']['FR'] = 'bonjour'
for translation in dictionary['EN']['hello'].all():
    print translation
```

Comment: "You aren't actually storing translations anywhere" I know :) I think I've used a confusing example for my purpose unfortunately.